# for and file command in shell

Tags: bash, file, shell

I have studied shell recently and I saw a sample code in the book and here it is:

File.sh

```
#!bin/bash

file_count=0;
for file in *
do
  let file+=1
done

echo "There are $file_count files in folder"
```

I tried this code and result is so weird.

I has three files in folder, `File.sh`, `Test.sh`, `Child.sh` but `file_count` value is 6 in result.

I print value of file and the result is:

```
child.sh
child.sh~
File.sh
Test~
Test.sh
Test.sh~
```

Wonder why this happened.

Comment: Don't you see the backup files created by your editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file names ended with `~` are backup files created by some famous text editors (like `gedit`). Once you open a file through such text editors, it would automatically creates a backup for each file you opened.

Comment: `gedit` isn't the only (and certainly not the first) program to do that. A lot of editors have this convention, since a very long time ago I believe.